# Find two values of one Column based on value of another column per ID

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, select, window-functions

I have a sqlite db with one table that called Loan. This table with sample data is here:
[Loan Table at sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ddc44)

This table contains below Columns:

```
mainindex | brindx | YearMonth | EmpID | VarNo | Name | LastName | CodepayID | CodepaySH | Lval | Lint | Lrmn
```

Now, I need a query to show desired result, contain

`[empid],[Codepayid],[Lval-1],[Lval-2],[Sum(Lint)],[Lrmn-1],[Lrmn-2]`,

With this Conditions:

```
[lVal-1] as Value of Lval Column of each Employee Correspond to their Lowest YearMonth
[lVal-2] as Value of Lval Column of each Employee Correspond to their Highest YearMonth
[Sum(Lint)] Sum of Lint Column for each Employee.
[Lrmn-1] as Value of Lrmn Column of each Emplyee Correspond to that Lowest YearMonth
[Lrmn-2] as Value of Lrmn Column of each Emplyee Correspond to that Highest YearMonth
```

For example:

```
select empid, Codepayid, Lval1, Lval2, Sum(Lint), Lrmn1, Lmrn2
   from Loan
   where CodepayID=649 and EmpID=12450400
   group by EmpID
```

Result:

| EmpID | CodepayID | Lval1 | Lval2 | Sum(Lint) | Lrmn1 | Lrmn2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12450400 | 649 | 405480 | 405485 | 270320 | 337900 | 202740 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FIRST_VALUE()` and `SUM()` window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmpID, CodepayID,
       FIRST_VALUE(Lval) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID, CodepayID ORDER BY YearMonth) LVal1,
       FIRST_VALUE(Lval) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID, CodepayID ORDER BY YearMonth DESC) LVal2,
       SUM(Lint) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID, CodepayID) sum_Lint,
       FIRST_VALUE(Lrmn) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID, CodepayID ORDER BY YearMonth) Lrmn1,
       FIRST_VALUE(Lrmn) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID, CodepayID ORDER BY YearMonth DESC) Lrmn2
FROM loan
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=82a13de7635031db52ceca0dc3a6f6ab).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It\`s a very clear logic, but it\`s not work on every db tools, ex: this query not run in SqliteStudio v 3.0.0. I`m not able to up vote because low reputation...

Comment: @TheAlien Window functions are supported in SQLite since version 3.25.0 (2018-09-15) and the current version is 3.36.0 (2021-06-18). If SQLiteStudio uses an older version then you should stop using it. Try DB Browser for SQLite: https://sqlitebrowser.org

Comment: I concur with @forpas - Not being able to run this is an indication that your SQLite instance is out of date.  SQLiteStudio is now on v.3.3.3, which includes SQLite 3.35.4, plus ***years*** of bug fixes.  *(v3.0.0 is from 2014!!!)*

Comment: @forpas Thanks again, I use SQLiteStudio 3.0.0 with latest precompiled dll SQLite [from here](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) , and now I able to use Window Function with best Performance, Thanks and I Approve this answer is the best between the 2 other answers.

Answer (score 1):

To get your desired result, first you have to find min and max value of column  YearMonth from the table for each employee and use those values as to get respective lval and lrmn for min and max YearMonth.

You can do it either in stored procedure or in single query, depends on your choice. Below is the query which will give your desire output

```
SELECT l.empid, l.CodepayID,  min(a.lval1) as lval1, max(b.lval2) as lval2 ,sum(l.lint) as lint,min(a.lrmn1) as lrmn1,max(b.lrmn2) as lrmn2
   FROM    loan l inner join
       (    SELECT empid,CodepayID, lval lval1, Lrmn lrmn1
            FROM loan ln 
            WHERE YEARMonth = (SELECT MIN(YearMonth) 
                                FROM loan 
                                WHERE empid = ln.EmpID and CodepayID = ln.CodepayID  
                                group by empid,CodepayID)
        ) a on l.empid = a.EmpID and l.CodepayID = a.codepayid
   inner  join
        (   SELECT empid, CodepayID, YearMonth,lval lval2, Lrmn lrmn2
            FROM loan ln
            WHERE YEARMonth = (SELECT MAX(YearMonth) 
                                FROM loan 
                                WHERE empid = ln.EmpID and CodepayID = ln.CodepayID  
                                GROUP BY empid,CodepayID)
        ) b on l.empid = b.EmpID and l.CodepayID = b.codepayid
   GROUP BY l.EmpID,l.Codepayid
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention and first Correct Answer.

Comment: I am glad that it helped you in some way.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is unnecessarily overly complex. Even if you don't want to use window functions, the following uses the same logic as the accepted answer with far less work for the database, completely avoiding correlated sub-queries...

```
SELECT
  l.empid,
  l.CodepayID,
  min(case when l.yearmonth = s.yearmonth_min then l.lval end) as lval1,
  max(case when l.yearmonth = s.yearmonth_max then l.lval end) as lval2, 
  sum(l.lint) as lint,
  min(case when l.yearmonth = s.yearmonth_min then l.lrmn end) as lrmn1,
  max(case when l.yearmonth = s.yearmonth_max then l.lrmn end) as lrmn2
FROM
  loan l
inner join
(
  select
    empid,
    CodepayID,
    min(yearmonth) as yearmonth_min,
    max(yearmonth) as yearmonth_max
  from
    loan
  group by
    empid,
    CodepayID
)
  s
    on  l.empid = s.empid
    and l.CodepayID = s.codepayid
group by
  l.EmpID, 
  l.Codepayid
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer, Your Query better performance than @PareshK, (2 second better on 10000 records) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68242304/4549193)